# Write to a file in S3 using Spark on EMR

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I use the following Scala code to create a text file in S3, with Apache Spark on AWS EMR.

```
def createS3OutputFile() {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Pi")
    val spark = new SparkContext(conf)
    // use s3n !
    val outputFileUri = s"s3n://$s3Bucket/emr-output/test-3.txt"
    val arr = Array("hello", "World", "!")
    val rdd = spark.parallelize(arr)
    rdd.saveAsTextFile(outputFileUri)
    spark.stop()
  }

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    createS3OutputFile()
  }
```

I create a fat JAR and upload it to S3. I then SSH into the cluster master and run the code with:

```
spark-submit \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --class "$class_name" \
    "s3://$s3_bucket/$app_s3_key"
```

I am seeing this in the S3 console: instead of files there are folders.

[image]

Each folder (for example test-3.txt) contains a long list of block files. Picture below:

[image]

How do I output a simple text file to S3 as the output of my Spark job?

Answer (score 5):

Try doing this:

`rdd.coalesce(1, shuffle = true).saveAsTextFile(...)`

My understanding is that the `shuffle = true` argument will cause this to occur in parallel so it will output a single text file, but do be careful with massive data files.

[Here](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/How-to-save-as-a-single-file-efficiently-td3014.html) are some more details on this issue at hand.

Comment: I'm new to Scala and Spark. What's the "canonical" way to get results from a Spark job? Is it writing to a file in the way I did? Is it creating a file using native Java functions?

Comment: @BlackSheep Really depends on the task at hand, there really isn't an official way. As for creating the file, each RDD partition will do the task you told it to do, so in this case each RDD partition will create a file and write to their own file.

Comment: This will still produce the folder structure, but with only one child `part-00000`.

Comment: @TimP Yea thats how Spark works, if you really want it in a single file thats something I'd do some post processing for.

Comment: @TheM00s3 Can you give an example of how to do this post-processing in the context of EMR? How do I save the output to S3 as a simple text file?

Comment: @BlackSheep You could use something like a python script where for each file in a directory you read its contents and output it to a new file and then delete the file you just read. If you'd like to use Java or Scala to do the same thing, its the same concept here.

Comment: @TheM00s3 Is that really the most canonical way to do it? It feels extremely hackish. Thousands of people use EMR, is this really how they get results out?

Comment: @BlackSheep You have to remember that most files that Spark is expecting to work with are probably massive so saving things to files is probably not the most preferred method of saving as such Spark hasen't invested much into the file system so you would be correct that it may feel hackish.  Most of the data my company buys though does come in spark form with many files and its actually quiet useful for us when it comes to processing them.

Answer (score -1):

Spark is distributed computing. It means your code is running on multiple nodes.

`saveAsTextFile()` method accepts `file path`, not the file name.

You could use `coalesce`() or `repartition` to decrease the number of part files. But still it will be created under the file path.

Alternatively, you can change the file name or merge multiple part files to single part file, using `FileUtil` class from `Hadoop File System`.

**Store RDD to S3**

```
rdd.saveAsTextFile("s3n://bucket/path/")
```

Also, check [this](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/6769/what-is-the-best-way-to-save-rdd-data-to-s3-bucket.html)

Comment: Can you give an example where the output of the job is saved to S3 as a file? You can pick the simplest output - a count (#). How do I save that as output in EMR?

Comment: @BlackSheep: Updated my answer to store rdd to s3.

Comment: `saveAsTextFile` is literally what I did as stated in the question. How does that solve my problem?